# Dynamically reloading ng-repeat data in the DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui

I have the following code in my view:
 

`<li ng-repeat="i in items">{{i.id}}</li>`

I would like the `ng-repeat` to be trigged dynamically when new values are added/removed from `items`. As in, if a new element is added to be beginning of `items` then it should be dynamically rendered to the DOM at the beginning and similarly if an element is added to the end of `items` that item should be rendered as the last list item. Is this dynamic changing of the DOM possible in angular?

Comment: Yes, should work out of the box that way.  Just make sure to `push` and `unshift` into the existing array. Angular will track by reference.

Comment: As angular js provides runtime data binding so any scope value when updated lead to apply() the dom UI you can see it here http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngController

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ng-repeat` should work this way out of the box.  However, you need to `push` or `unshift` into the array so that the correct watch will fire.  Angular will track the array by reference.

Here is a [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NbK7Nt?p=preview).

HTML:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.0" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
      {{ item }}
    </div>
    <button ng-click="add()">Add</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.items = ['hi', 'hey', 'hello'];

    $scope.add = function() {

      $scope.items.push('wazzzup');
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, but a setTimeOut to append an element does not seem to dynamically append it to the list.

Comment: You must use `$timeout` angular service or `$scope.$apply` to trigger the angular `$digest`.

Comment: I was originally testing ng-repeat with setTimeout which was what prompted me to ask the question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Aha, this is a good tip. so replacing an entire $scope.data.array with ['item1', 'item2'] etc. for example will NOT update the view automagically. use a $scope.$apply closure (see this for more info : http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html) to let angular know something has updated outside the stuff that it watches, apparently.

Comment: How to make sure the item goes to the top of the list? I have an issue where the item is added to the bottom in my view, however in my array I put it in the beginning of the array

Comment: Hey cool, @DavinTryon and I tried this method and failed the attempt. Can you take a look at my codes here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29323115/reloading-ng-repeat-data-failed-what-did-i-do-wrong

Answer (score 1):

You can use $rootScope intead of $scope to set the property items.

This way the property is global and will be updated.

```
myApp.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {

    $rootScope.items = ['hi', 'hey', 'hello'];

    $scope.add = function() {
        $rootScope.items.push('wazzzup');
    }
});
```