# Reloading ng-repeat data failed, what did I do wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, angularjs

I like to reload an `ng-repeat` element after I process some data, but it failed. I like to know what I did wrong.

So the general process id that I load some data from "iframe.php" and then insert the data into a invisible div tag for jquery to map the data (in html format) into json format and save the json data into a variable called `tableObject`. And then I will use `scope.$apply(scope.showCards)` to push the data into my `$scope.cards`.

Here is my code:

```
var app = angular.module('rabbit', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'ngMdIcons']),
    apiURL = 'iframe.php',
    tableObject = [];

$.ajax({
  url: "iframe.php",
  crossDomain: true,
  dataType: "html",
  success: function(data) {
    var json = data.substring(data.indexOf('<tr class = "pfrow2">') - 21);
    json = json.substring(0,json.indexOf('<td style="margin-top: 20px" colspan="2">'));
    json = json.substring(0,json.lastIndexOf('</td>') + 5);
    function widthChange() {
      if (json.indexOf('&width=130') != -1) {
        json = json.replace('&width=130','&width=300');
        widthChange();
      } else {
        // console.log(json);
        $('#json').html(json);
        var headers = ["name","kind","type","age","size","thumb","link"];
        tableObject = $("#json tr").map(function(i){
          var row = {};
          $(this).find('td').each(function(i){
            var rowName = headers[i];
            row[rowName] = $(this).text().trim();
          });
          $(this).find('td.legacy img').each(function(){
            var rowName = headers[5];
            row[rowName] = $(this).attr('src');
          });
          $(this).find('td.legacy a').each(function(){
            var rowName = headers[6];
            row[rowName] = $(this).attr('href');
          });
          return row;
        }).get();
        console.table(tableObject);
        $('#json').html('');
        var scope = angular.element($('#content')).scope();
        scope.$apply(scope.showCards);
      }
    }
    widthChange();
  },
  error: function() {
    console.log('error');
  },
});

app.controller('cardCtrl', function ($scope, $log, $mdDialog) {
  var showCards = function() {
    $scope.cards.push(tableObject);
  };
  $scope.cards = tableObject;
});
```

Here is the `ng-repeat` element in HTML:

```
  <div id="content" layout-sm="col" layout="row" layout-wrap ng-controller="cardCtrl">
    <md-card ng-repeat="card in cards" class="noselect" md-ink-ripple>
      <img src="{{card.thumb}}" alt="{{card.name}}">
      <h2>{{card.name}}</h2>
      <p>{{card.type}}</p>
      <p>{{card.age}}</p>
      <p>{{card.size}}</p>
      <a href="{{card.link}}"></a>
    </md-card>
  </div>
```

Comment: Have you considered using the $http module instead of jquery's $.ajax? Because that would remove your need to use scope.$apply.

Comment: @TiagoMartins yes, I used $http initially but abolished the code later because of some injection errors. I suspect $http returns a different (html) object from $.ajax, which makes it impossible for my code to manipulate. I can upload the code if null's solution does not work for me.

Comment: @TiagoMartins null's solution works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's abit hard to see what is going wrong exactly, but I'm guessing the `tableObject` gets reassigned to a different array instance: the controller is always binding that empty array you declared globally (which are quite evil).

There are several things you can do. Most easiest is to refactor the jquery statement to a factory method the controller can call.

```
app.factory('myAjaxThingy', function($q) {
  return function() {

      // Create a defer to async promise the consumer a result
      var defer = $q.defer();

      $.ajax({ 
        /* ... */
          success: function(data) {

            // Construct the array here

            var tableObject;

            /* ... */
            /* all that parsing magic goes here */
            /* ... */            

            // Resolve the promise
            // Note: no whacky angular.element().scope() and no scope.aplly()
            defer.resolve(tableObject);
          }
      });

      // Return the promise object
      return defer.promise;
  };
});

app.controller('MyController', function(myAjaxThingy) {

  myAjaxThingy().then(function(result) {
    $scope.cards = result;
  });

});
```

This way you can even re-execute the call if needed. Also note that angular has a pretty good `$http` service that can do the same as `$.ajax`.

Comment: I did use $http method to create a factory initially and failed the attempt. I am going to try using $q now and see how it works out for me.

Comment: Wow you are the awesome Angular God.